# Using vim's printf in a substitution

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to convert a date format from
m/d/yyyy 7/1/2016

occurring once per line to YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00

I have the search & parameter part working and can swap the order etc.,

However I wanted to do it using vim's printf and have come up with the following...

```
%s/\(\d\+\)\/\(\d\+\)\/\(\d\+\)/\=printf('%d-%02d-%02d 00:00:00', \3, \1, \2)/
```

I get...

```
E15: Invalid expression: \3, \1, \2)
E116: Invalid arguments for function printf('%d-%02d-%02d 00:00:00', \3, \1, \2)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use  `submatch()` function:

```
:%s/\(\d\+\)\/\(\d\+\)\/\(\d\+\)/\=printf('%d-%02d-%02d 00:00:00', submatch(3),
submatch(1), submatch(2))/
```

---

```
:help submatch()
```

> ```
> submatch({nr}[, {list}])                                submatch()
>                 Only for an expression in a :substitute command or
>                 substitute() function.
>                 Returns the {nr}'th submatch of the matched text.  When {nr}
>                 is 0 the whole matched text is returned.
>                 Note that a NL in the string can stand for a line break of a
>                 multi-line match or a NUL character in the text.
>                 Also see sub-replace-expression.(...)
> ```

Comment: Excellent! top marks and thank you very much. I expended 'quite a lot of time' looking at this and much to my chagrin, couldn't resolve it. I am very grateful.

Comment: Happy to help !

Comment: @SteamedUp `%s,\v(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+),[...]` `:h /magic` and `:h E146` :)